# Meteor.call executes server method but brings no response

Tags: meteor, react-native, android-emulator

- I am trying to call a Meteor method from react-native application using Meteor.call
- The method is getting called which I verified from server console logs,but response value is not received on client side.
- **React native code**

  ```
  import Meteor, { createContainer } from 'react-native-meteor';
  const SERVER_URL = 'ws://172.16.177.81:3000/websocket';
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { text: 'locationname' };
  }

  //Connecting and subscribing to Meteor
  componentWillMount() {   
      Meteor.connect(SERVER_URL);   
      Meteor.subscribe('items');
  }

  ... 

  try {   
      var searchQuery="africa"
      console.log("calling findPac... waiting for response");
      Meteor.call('Items.findPac',searchQuery, (err, result) => {
          if(err){
              console.log("Error in calling"+err);                
          }
          else{
              console.log("result");
          }
      });             
  }
  catch(e){
  console.log("Caught exception: " + e);
  }
  ```
- No console logs inside **Meteor.call** are printed nor there is any exception caught.
- **Meteor Server code**
- **Main.js**

  ```
  import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
  import '/imports/api/items';

  Meteor.startup(() => {
      console.log("meteor server started");
  });
  ```
- **Items.js**

  ```
  import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
  import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
  const Items = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
  var util = require("util");
  import { EJSON } from 'meteor/ejson'
  Meteor.methods({
     'Items.findPac': (sq) => {
      console.log(“Returning result after processing input”);
      return (EJSON.stringify(EJSON.stringify([]))); 
      },
  });
  Meteor.publish('items', () => {
    return Items.find();
  });
  export default Items;
  ```
- The console log `Returning result after processing input` is printed on meteor server terminal but no return response sent is received on react-native client side.
- The meteor server is installed on local machine and client is running on Android emulator

Comment: You are using Meteor through the react-native-meteor package that didn't have a recent update. Have you tried to test your code using directly Meteor using import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'?

Comment: Is meteor available to be installed as npm package in react-native project?